# select mid part of string based on total str length into new column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How would I pull the year section of a string based on a dynamically changing length,

**example data**

```
Name
C:/Users/Documents/Ownership_1_Year_2015.csv
C:/Users/Documents/Non_Ownersip_1_Year_2016.csv
C:/Users/Documents/Ownership_1_Year_2016.csv
```

The formula I'm playing with is

```
df['Name_Stripped'] = df['Name'].str[:-4]
```

which obviously takes out .csv, and I trieed a len(str)-8 would provide a dynamic start value, but no surprise it's confused as all heck as to what I'm trying to calculate the length of. I do figure a for loop would work with the length of x being called each time, but Im sure there is a much more pythonic way I'm not aware of..

Expected outcome:

```
 Name
2015
2016
2016
```

Answer (score 2):

Can this be a solution?

```
 df['Name_Stripped'] = df['Name'].str[-8:-4]
```

Output:

```
                                              Name Name_Stripped
0     C:/Users/Documents/Ownership_1_Year_2015.csv          2015
1  C:/Users/Documents/Non_Ownersip_1_Year_2016.csv          2016
2     C:/Users/Documents/Ownership_1_Year_2016.csv          2016
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest extract integers with length 4:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.extract('(\d{4})')
print (df)
   Name
0  2015
1  2016
2  2016
```